# Globalize3 order records by translated attributes and taking fallbacks into consideration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fallback, globalize3

Im having troubles with awesome Globalize3 gem. For now I`m having two languages :en and :ru. And :ru falls back to :en like this

```
#/config/initializers/globalize.rb
Globalize.fallbacks = {:ru => [:ru, :en]}
```

In my controller I am trying to sort the whole collection of translated records either by name translations or by translations fallback values. But `with_translations()` does not seem to give me such opportunity!

```
Country.with_translations(:ru).order('country_translations.name ASC')
#this filters out those who have no :ru translations (BUT THEY SHOLD USE FALLBACKS!)
```

so to retrieve all records i can pass an array of locales:

```
Country.with_translations([:ru, :en]).order('country_translations.name ASC')
#but this completely ruins the sorting order (DAMN NOTHING IS SORTED)
```

and the only simple thing i want is to get fallbacks and sorting all togather! So we need somehow get all records only sorted by available name value.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved this by digging into Globalize3 source. It uses `with_locales` scope to get records that have proper locales present. I just needed them all:

```
Model.includes(:translations).
       with_locales(I18n.available_locales).
       order('model_translations.name ASC')
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 3):

Would have left this as a comment, but don't have the reputation yet, so figured I might as well leave this as an answer.

1. In Rails 4, that query as it is currently written throws a long deprecation warning about implicit joins (which is what you're doing by referencing the `model_translations` table in the where cause).
2. I believe you are trying return `Model` records, not `Model::Translation` records. As such, I think you can swap the `includes` for a `join`, which should be more performant and gets rid of the deprecation warning.

In my Rails 4 app, the join worked perfectly, but I haven't tested it in Rails 3.